# civiMail doesn't work

Tags: civimail

I'm getting this error message trying to send a bulk mail from civimail:

Finished execution of Send Scheduled Mailings with result: Failure, Error message: API permission check failed for Group/get call; insufficient permission: require access CiviCRM

Who is is that needs permission?  The logged in drupal user?  Civicrm contact? SMTP user?  Someone else?

The mail accounts from which the mail is sent ask for a username and password.  Same question, what sort of user is needed here?

Thanks,

Jack Donohue

Answer (score 3):

Its the CMS user that you have used to set CiviCRM cron needs some administrator permission to process your Schedule jobs. Please check the cron user role and assign necessary permission.

Cheers

Pradeep